# How to use predicate search with multiple keys in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, predicate

I want to apply search filter with first name and last name and I've done with single field search but I want to apply search with both i.e., first name & last name.

```
var cityData = [[String: Any]]()


cityData.append(["id":1,"city":"Chicago","last_name":"Swire","first_name":"Sharlene"])
cityData.append(["id":1,"city":"Allahabad","last_name":"Singh","first_name":"Abhay"])
cityData.append(["id":1,"city":"Delhi","last_name":"Jaiswal","first_name":"Shikhar"])



let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains[c] %@", searchTerm)
let searchData = cityData.filter { predicate.evaluate(with: $0["first_name"] as? String ?? "") }
```

but the above code is filtering only for first name but I need to filter from last name as well

Comment: Any feedback on the answers you have received?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find city based on first name or last name you can add or condition in the filter operation like this
`let searchData = cityData.filter { predicate.evaluate(with: $0["first_name"] as? String ?? "") || predicate.evaluate(with: $0["last_name"] as? String ?? "") }`

Please see the below exmple:

```
var cityData = [[String: Any]]()
    
    
    cityData.append(["id":1,"city":"Chicago","last_name":"Swire","first_name":"Sharlene"])
    cityData.append(["id":1,"city":"Allahabad","last_name":"Singh","first_name":"Abhay"])
    cityData.append(["id":1,"city":"Delhi","last_name":"Jaiswal","first_name":"Shikhar"])
    
    
    
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains[c] %@", "l")
    let searchData = cityData.filter { predicate.evaluate(with: $0["first_name"] as? String ?? "") || predicate.evaluate(with: $0["last_name"] as? String ?? "") }
    print(searchData)
```

This will print results:

```
[["last_name": "Swire", "first_name": "Sharlene", "city": "Chicago", "id": 1], ["city": "Delhi", "last_name": "Jaiswal", "id": 1, "first_name": "Shikhar"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all use a struct rather than a dictionary, this avoids all the ugly type cast

```
struct CityData {
    let id : Int
    let city, firstName, lastName : String
}

var cityData = [CityData]()

cityData.append(CityData(id: 1, city: "Chicago", firstName: "Sharlene", lastName: "Swire"))
cityData.append(CityData(id: 2, city: "Allahabad", firstName: "Abhay", lastName: "Singh"))
cityData.append(CityData(id: 3, city: "Delhi", firstName: "Shikhar", lastName: "Jaiswal"))
```

There is no need for using `NSPredicate`, Swift has an efficient native method to `filter` arrays and `range(of:options:)` with `caseInsensitive` option does the same as the `[c]` attribute in `NSPredicate`

```
let searchData = cityData.filter { $0.firstName.range(of: searchTerm, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil ||
                                   $0.lastName.range(of: searchTerm, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
}
```